# Запись в файл свойства TextBox.Text (.NET 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся со странной проблемой. 
Имеется инфа, считывающаяся в текстбоксы из файла. В этой форме она меняется, если это нужно и перезаписывается по нажатию на кнопку.
Событие нажатия на кнопку:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("options/account.dll", FileMode.Open);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
sw.Write(textBox1.Text + "\n"); //логин
sw.Write(textBox6.Text + "\n");  //представление
sw.Write(textBox2.Text + "\n"); //
sw.Write(textBox3.Text + "\n");
sw.Write(textBox4.Text + "\n");
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    sw.Write("yes" + "\n");
else if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
    sw.Write("no" + "\n");
sw.Write(textBox5.Text + "\n");
sw.Write(textBox7.Text + "\n");
sw.Write(textBox8.Text);
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Произойдет перезапуск программы");
this.Close();
Application.Restart();
```

Все ок, все работает. НО! Допустим в textBox8.Text было "Иванов Иван". Изменю на "Иванов Иван1", нажму кнопку, все перезапишется, все будут довольны 
Но если изменю поле текстбокса с "Иванов Иван" на "Иванов Ива", нажму кнопку, поле не перезаписывается, т.е. в файле так и остается "Иванов Иван". Как решить эту проблему и с чем это связано? Скажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы используете `FileMode.Open`, который лишь открывает файл, но не удаляет его текущее содержимое.

В результате вы просто перезаписываете часть данных поверх.

Например, если в файле было `Иванов Иван`, а вы пишете поверх `Иванов Ива`, то вы перезаписываете по новой все символы, а последний не трогаете.

Используйте `FileMode.Create`.

---

Я бы часть вашей программы, занимающуюся записью, оформил как-то так:

```
string[] lines = new string[]
{
    textBox1.Text,
    textBox6.Text,
    textBox2.Text,
    textBox3.Text,
    textBox4.Text,
    checkBox1.Checked ? "yes" : "no",
    textBox5.Text,
    textBox7.Text,
    textBox8.Text
};

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Comment: спасибо!) но в предыдущих textbox-ах такого не было, только в последнем почему-то

Comment: @DmitryShulga: Представьте сами, если у вас первый текст короче, то остаются всё равно символы от от последнего текстбокса. Просто текст второго в файле появляется раньше.